# mac os x what the two forward slash root is?

Tags: root

On my mac os x I have two roots the second one has two forward slashes. //  wondering what that is. I searched everywhere but cant find any information about this.

Comment: Where do you see the "two roots"? In a path the slash can be repeated without any consequences. `///Users/myname/////Library` is exactly the same as `/Users/myname/Library`

Answer (score 2):

This is a strange part of the [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) specification.

See [unix, difference between path starting with '/' and '//'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12283/unix-difference-between-path-starting-with-and).

Two slashes in the beginning of a pathname are interpreted in an implementation-defined way. As far as I know, only cygwin actually takes // to mean something different than / (//FOO maps to a network drive called FOO, / maps to the local root). On most other systems / and // are the same. Note that /// is interpreted as /.

Your shell is I suspect bash and it keeps the // just in case the OS does something special with it. On OSX it is the same as /.